# Make nothing overlap an absolute div

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute div which looks fine on full screen.

On screen resize, the absolute div overlaps `<p>`.

How can I make sure that no matter the screen size, the div is not overlapping anything (or being overlapped) and has about 15px spacing from each element?

```css
p {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "AvenirNextLTW01-Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-block" style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 60px;"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4022333/Blog/TOFU/quote.png?t=1528796131649" style="width: 58px;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 70px;" class="quotation">
    <p style="font-family: AvenirLight; color: #74818a; font-size: 28px; line-height: 28px; font-style: italic;">"As a technology buyer, when I am selecting between potential technology solution providers, I ask myself not ‘ if’, but ‘when’, we run into challenges, which solution provider do I most want to be resolving the issues with?"</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: not sure why you need it absolute, just make it relative and use margin instead of top and left

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using absolute/relative  divs to create this layout ?

Try using `flex` as i did in the below snippet.

```css
p {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "AvenirNextLTW01-Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

.quote-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-block" style=""><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4022333/Blog/TOFU/quote.png?t=1528796131649" style="width: 58px;">
  <div class="quotation">
    <p style="margin-left: 20px;font-family: AvenirLight; color: #74818a; font-size: 28px; line-height: 28px; font-style: italic;">"As a technology buyer, when I am selecting between potential technology solution providers, I ask myself not ‘ if’, but ‘when’, we run into challenges, which solution provider do I most want to be resolving the issues with?"</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
p {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "AvenirNextLTW01-Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}
.quotation:before{
  background:url("https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4022333/Blog/TOFU/quote.png?t=1528796131649") no-repeat left top;
  width:79px;
  height:58px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";      
}
.quotation{
  position:relative;
  padding-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-block" style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 60px;">
  <div class="quotation">
    <p style="font-family: AvenirLight; color: #74818a; font-size: 28px; line-height: 28px; font-style: italic;">"As a technology buyer, when I am selecting between potential technology solution providers, I ask myself not ‘ if’, but ‘when’, we run into challenges, which solution provider do I most want to be resolving the issues with?"</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```